# limit_text is only outputting plain text and not showing bold font

Tags: php, html

I have some code that outputs a title and a description for a list of posts. I am trying to limit the length of text for both. The title is $story->title, and outputs just fine. However the description, represented by $story->excerpt in the code, contains html tags in the database. The limit_text function seems to strip these tags from the text. I think I need to limit the characters differently or need a function to allow those tags to work.

I have tried some functions that allows the tags to be seen but not function properly. But I am new to php in general so I don't know many functions.

```
<?php
    foreach($stories as $story) {
        echo '<h2><a href="'.BASE_URL.'/'.$story->slug.'">'.limit_text($story->title, 80).'</a></h2>';
        if(!empty($story->excerpt)) {
            echo '<p>'.limit_text($story->excerpt, 150).'</p>';
        } else {
            echo limit_text($story->body, 150);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I found the function for `limit_text`

```
function limit_text($string, $limit = 140) {
$string = preg_replace('/<figcaption>.*?<\/figcaption>/','',$string);
$string = preg_replace('/<div class=\"wp_image_caption\">.*?<\/div>/','',$string);
$string = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$string);

$string = substr($string, strpos($string, "<p><strong>"));
$string = strip_tags($string);
$string = substr($string, 0, $limit);
$string = $string.'...';
return $string;
}
```

Comment: `limit_text` is not a built-in PHP function, so we have no way of knowing what it does. It's unique to your application or framework, so you'll have to look there for how it works.

Comment: You know, thats what I thought. But because it works it must exist somewhere in my code, right? Having a hard time finding it. Ill try to do a search.

Comment: My guess is it just takes the first 150 characters of a string and chops the rest off hence chopping off the ending html tags.

Comment: The tag I need is `<strong>` , and its within the limited text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why my tags were being stripped was the `strip_tags`method right in the function. Duh. Hehe. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: That'll do it. Be careful removing it, though. If your function to create an excerpt permits an opening `<b>` but removes the closing `</b>` (because it's past the character limit cut-off), everything after it will be bold. It's easy to mess up your entire page this way.

Comment: The `$story->excerpt` only gets used in a couple places on the site. And I also created a new function that is identical to `limit_text` but without the `strip_tags` method and am using that to try and further isolate it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Try this limit text function instead

```
public function limitText($text, $len)
{
    $text = preg_match('#<\s*?b\b[^>]*>(.*?)</b\b[^>]*>#s', $text, $matches);
    return "<b>" . substr($text,0, $len) . "</b>";
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it just replaced my entire string with a '0'.